# Solve $x^2+tx'+x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $x^2+tx'+x=0$

this is clearly a Bernoulli's equation so I make a substitution $z=\frac 1 x$
$$x=\frac 1z$$
$$x'=\frac {-z'}{z^2}$$
$$\frac {1}{z^2}-\frac {tz'}{z^2}+\frac 1 z=0$$
$$1-tz'+z=0$$
$$z+1=tz'$$
$$log|z+1|=log|t|+C$$
$$z=Ct+1$$
$$x=\frac {1}{Ct+1}$$

But the actual answer to this is 
$$x=\frac {e^C}{t-e^C}$$
Wolfram alpha also shows the second answer, so my question is where did I make a mistake, and if I didnt then why these two solutions differ so much?

Comment: They don't differ much: If you let $C'=e^-C$, the latter equation becomes $x=\frac{1}{C't-1}$.

Comment: There is a mistake in the integration step that follows $z+1=tz'$.

Comment: Actually the general answer is either $x=c/(t-c)$ and $x=-1$, or $x=1/(ct-1)$ and $x=0$. Thus the answer $x=e^C/(t-e^C)$ "misses" a lot of solutions.

Answer (score 4):

$$z+1 = t\, z'$$
gives:
$$\frac{z'}{z+1}=\frac{1}{t},$$
$$\log(z+1) = \log(t)-C,$$
$$ z+1 = t\, e^{-C},$$
$$ z = t\, e^{-C} -1,$$
$$ x = \frac{1}{t\,e^{-C}-1} = \frac{e^C}{t-e^C}.$$

Comment: This misses the solutions $x=c/(t-c)$ with $c\leqslant0$.

Answer (score 0):

In the step form $\log$'s (there you should have written $\log{|t|} + C$ on the rand hand side also) to $z = Ct + 1$. You should get $z+1 = A t$ (you cannot use the same symbol for new constant) and then $$x =\frac{1}{At -1}\text{.}$$

Now, if you multiply enumerator and denominator of RHS by constant $\frac{1}{A}$ you get, if $A>0$, WolframAlpha's form, because there exists such $c\in\mathbb{R}$ that $e^C = A$. Since constant A in our case can also be negative, WolframAlpha's solution is not completly right. Note that $A$ can equal zero. In that case you obtain solution $x = -1$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Also, by playing with differentials, we lost a solution $x = 0$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$.